# r magick highlight picture

Tags: r, imagemagick

I want to highlight parts of a picture by adding a white fill to it, similar to what is done in this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78378/highlighting-part-of-an-image.

I'm using magick and the code below.

```
library(magick)
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png") %>%
  image_colorize( opacity = 80 , color = "white") %>% 
  image_draw(.)
rect(40, 20, 150, 150, border = "red", lty = "dashed", lwd = 5)
rect(80, 170, 150, 300, border = "blue", lty = "solid", lwd = 5)
```

and the result is this

[image]

How to I remove the white fill inside the squares?

Comment: I do not understand. Your question is confusing. At the top you ask to add white fill. But at the bottom you ask to remove the white fill. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @fmw42 Fred, OP is adding 80% white fill to cover entire image with the `colorize()` command on line 3 but actually only wants that in the areas **outside** the red and blue highlighted rectangles rather than everywhere. I think 

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that Mark Setchell's comment is correct, then with Imagemagick command line, you can do the following. Sorry, I do not know RMagick.

Input:

[image]

What I do is:

```
1. Read the input image.
2. Copy the input image and add 80% to make it whiter
3. Copy the image and fill it with white, then draw a black rectangle where you want to keep the original color. This will be a mask image
4. Use the mask image to composite the original and the white image together
5. Add a blue border
6. Save the result


convert lena.png \
\( -clone 0 -evaluate add 80% \) \
\( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 \
-fill black -draw "rectangle 100,100 150,150" -alpha off \) \
-compose over -composite \
-fill none -stroke blue -strokewidth 5 \
-draw "rectangle 100,100 150,150" \
result.jpg
```

[image]

Adjust the 80% to whatever value you like to make the input whiter.

Perhaps 50% is more pleasing.

[image]

Comment: Nice work! I hope I understood the question correctly